# Animate like button when click on it

Tags: jquery, css, twitter

I want some animation like Twitter's Like button . I've taken screenshot from Twitter . Here is some images from it's animation:

1:

[image]

2:

[image]

3:

[image]

Do you know any good jQuery library or CSS3 library to use animation like this?

Comment: This is the thing: http://codepen.io/chrismabry/pen/ZbjZEj

Comment: @NirmalyaGhosh I really  appreciate it.

Comment: Please set your comment as answer. Do you know any site for exploring animation like this? (except  http://codepen.io/)

Comment: Done. You can search in codepen for some wonderful examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="heart"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.heart {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-image:url(  'https://abs.twimg.com/a/1446542199/img/t1/web_heart_animation.png');
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:2900%;
 }

 .heart:hover {
  background-position:right;
 }

 .animating {
  animation: heart-burst .8s steps(28) 1;
 }

 @keyframes heart-burst {
 from {background-position:left;}
 to { background-position:righ;}
 }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(".heart").on('click touchstart', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('animating');
});


$(".heart").on('animationend', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('animating');
});
```

Check the fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/0yyegtv9/

Answer (score 0):

This is the thing that you are looking for:
http://codepen.io/chrismabry/pen/ZbjZEj

```
/* when a user clicks, toggle the 'is-animating' class */
$(".heart").on('click touchstart', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('is_animating');
});

/*when the animation is over, remove the class*/
$(".heart").on('animationend', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('is_animating');
});
```