# Put a text in side of jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I found this post [Animate like button when click on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693991/animate-like-button-when-click-on-it), but I want to know how I can put a text side of animation.

I tried:

```
<div class="heart">TEXT</div>
```

&&

```
<div class="heart"><p>TEXT</p></div>
```

But the text come over the animation...
I just want the text in right side of animation.
How to make this ?

Comment: div with the heart class was set as an icon and not a container. so why don't you try to put the **text** outside of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated snippet base on the fiddle you are trying to do.

```js
$(".heart").on('click touchstart', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('animating');
});


$(".heart").on('animationend', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('animating');
});
```

```css
.heart {
  float:left;
  margin-top: -1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-image:url(  'https://abs.twimg.com/a/1446542199/img/t1/web_heart_animation.png');
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:2900%;
 }

 .heart:hover {
  background-position:right;
 }

 .animating {
  animation: heart-burst .8s steps(28) 1;
 }

 @keyframes heart-burst {
 from {background-position:left;}
 to { background-position:righ;}
 }
```

```html
<div class="heart-container">
  <div class="heart"></div>
  <p>TEXT</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 divs. One for the heart and one for the text. Then in css use position: relative or position:absolute to play around with the alignmente.

Maybe you'll also need to play with the z-index so you make sure the heart is in the back.

In this example, my heart is just a square. The principle is the same.

```css
.heart {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
<div class="text">Love</div>
```